# How to draw a border to a win32 control in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to owner-draw a red border to a  EDIT or Push button in C++ win32 api. NO MFC Please.
I have gotten this far. Drawing a black border but most if not all the hButtonDC,hButtonBitmap are undeclared.

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
HBRUSH hBrush;
BeginPaint(hwndButton2, &ps);

//  Create memory DC to contain hButtonBitmap

hButtonDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ps.hdc);
hButtonBitmap = SelectObject(hButtonDC, hButtonBitmap);

//  Create second memory DC where the button borders will be drawn and select into this DC an empty bitmap with the
//  size of the button bitmap

hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ps.hdc);
hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(ps.hdc, ps.rcPaint.right, ps.rcPaint.bottom);
hBitmap = SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

//  Copy hButtonDC into hMemDC

BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0,  ps.rcPaint.right, ps.rcPaint.bottom, hButtonDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

//  Paint the button borders with black pixels (1 pixel width)

PatBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, ps.rcPaint.right - 1, 1, BLACKNESS);
PatBlt(hMemDC, ps.rcPaint.right - 1, 0, 1, ps.rcPaint.bottom, BLACKNESS);
PatBlt(hMemDC,  0, ps.rcPaint.bottom - 1, ps.rcPaint.right , 1, BLACKNESS);
PatBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, 1, ps.rcPaint.bottom - 1, BLACKNESS);

//  Paint the button with drawn borders to its window DC, ps.hdc .

BitBlt(ps.hdc, 0, 0, ps.rcPaint.right, ps.rcPaint.bottom, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); 

//  Delete hBitmap e hMemDC

DeleteObject(SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap));
DeleteDC(hMemDC);

//  Delete hButtonDC

SelectObject(hButtonDC, hButtonBitmap);
DeleteDC(hButtonDC);

EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

Comment: @SteveWellens: There is nothing wrong with using the WinAPI if the purpose is right.

Comment: Put HDC in front of hButtonDC and HBITMAP in front of hButtonBitmap.  Writing Windows GUI code is not exactly the best way to get started on learning basic programming skills.  Tackle something smaller first, console app style.

Comment: @Jesse: That's a pretty big IF.  There is also nothing wrong with using two sticks to start a fire if a Bic lighter isn't available.

Comment: @Steve: Assembly language is going to have to call functions from the Windows API in order to get anything done. I just don't see how this is a valid comparison. You simply *can't* program Windows without interacting with the API. The only thing you can do is use a wrapper library written by someone else, which provides varying degrees of encapsulation from the API. Sometimes that's practical/productive, other times it's not. Like when you don't want huge dependencies and inflated EXEs. It's also not like the Windows API isn't worth learning altogether, considering it's used everywhere.

Comment: Beyond that, I'm rather exhausted by that general line of argument. C++ is also a lower level language than C# or Java; does that mean it's obsolete and no one should use it?

Comment: @PotentVenom: The problem is that you're not declaring the `hButtonDC` and `hButtonBitmap` variables anywhere. You *assign* to them at the top, but you never tell the compiler to allocate space for those variables. As Hans suggests, solve that problem by making the assignment also a declaration: `HDC hButtonDC = CreateCompatibleDC(ps.hdc);` and `HDC hButtonBitmap = SelectObject(hButtonDC, hButtonBitmap);` The rest of the code looks fine, but I don't have a compiler in front of me other than my eyes...

Comment: @CodyGray - You have successfully made a 'straw man' argument.